# Synchronizing three linux processes

Tags: c, linux, bash, daemon

I have 3 different linux processes (daemons). One is the main one which takes care about initialization of the IPC and some other stuff. After the initialization is done one of the remaining processes must start and run until it must be restarted. Which process is started depends on the configuration stored in a XML file. I must be able to restart all of the processes i.e. via /etc/init.d/xxx restart.

How can I start one of the remaining two processes depending on the configuration and also implement the restart so all processes restart at one time?

Comment: Make the master program `fork()`/`exec()` the proper program after it's done with initialization and reading the config file?

Comment: If I understand you I should create a fourth simple master program which first creates a child which calls the main program using execve() wait for a i.e. semaphore that the initialization is finished. And then call one of the remaining processes using the master program.

Comment: That would be another possibility. I was thinking of just extending the first program - but I hadn't considered you might not have the ability to do that if it's not your own code...